# How to draw a double down arrow in xypic?

Tags: arrows, xy-pic

I want to have a pair of arrows going downward in a similar way to this picture(it's from AWWAPP so forgive me for the quality): [image]

Comment: Welcome between the group of TeX.SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two individual arrows with a small offset:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[all]{xy} 


\begin{document}


\xymatrix{
  \ar@<-0.5ex>[d]\ar@<0.5ex>[d] \\ 
  {}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For people who might prefer `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd} 


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzcd}
  \arrow[d]\arrow[d,xshift=1ex]   \\
    {}
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I have upvoted you. Please can you edit your answer putting an image? Thank you.

Comment: @Sebastiano Two arrows would be a boring image

Comment: I respect your opinion but the image give an idea. :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano ????

Comment: @Sebastiano I added them

Comment: The images are not useless. For example, the arrow tips in the two examples are different.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Thank you very much much.

Comment: Thank you so much.